# Change vuetify theme on laravel

Tags: laravel, vuetify.js

How can I change the vuetify theme on laravel?

```js
import Vuetify from "../plugins/vuetify"
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
    theme: {
        themes: {
            light: {
                primary: '#3f51b5',
                secondary: '#b0bec5',
                accent: '#8c9eff',
                error: '#b71c1c',
              },
        },
      },
})


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: Vuetify,
});
```

This is in my app.js and it doesnt seem to change the values for the colour variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, i suppose that you have to change it in the "../plugins/vuetify.js".

If you have a plugins folder, it shall mean that you're using vuetify-loader.

Your file should look somehow like this

```js
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
    
    Vue.use(Vuetify)
    
    export default new Vuetify({
      theme: {
        themes: {
          light: {
            primary: '#3f51b5',
            secondary: '#b0bec5',
            accent: '#8c9eff',
            error: '#b71c1c'
          }
        }
      }
    })
```